# Parsing XML using minidom with regex

Tags: python, xml, regex, unicode

I am trying to parse some XML, looking for elements with the tag name "ip"  Ultimately I need a list of strings with IP addresses in them.   Here is what I have tried:

```
def parseHosts(xmldoc):
  hostsNode = xmldoc.firstChild
  xmlList = hostsNode.getElementsByTagName("ip")

  ipList = []
  for ip in xmlList:
    ipList.append(ip.childNodes[0].nodeValue)

  print ipList
>>>[u'172.16.60.92', u'172.16.60.89', u'\n              ', u'172.16.60.90', u'172.16.60.91', u'172.16.60.93']
```

That's OK.   but I need a list of strings of IP addresses...   I don't want nodes that are empty.  just a nice list of addresses like this:

```
['172.16.60.1', '172.16.60.5', 172.16.60.100']
```

I have tried a bit of regex with a list comprehension

```
  regex = re.compile(r'172\.16\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')
  [m.group(0) for l in ipList for m in [regex.search(1)] if m]
```

But I get the following error

```
File "myParser.py", line 47, in parseHosts
[m.group(0) for l in ipList for m in [regex.search(1)] if m]
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

and try as I might I can not find out with type ipList is using `type(ipList)` nor can I figure out how to make this stuff a string.

Also... getting rid of that Unicode stuff would be good.

Clearly I have gone off the deep end here somewhere, but I am not sure where to look.

Comment: Where do you see any "uuencode stuff" to get rid of?

Comment: Also, why can't you use `type(ipList)`? And what good do you expect it to do anyway? You create it as an empty `list` and then call `append` on it, so what could it be besides a `list`?

Comment: uuencode stuff is in the ipList  u'172.16.60.92'

Comment: That's not uuencoded. uuencoded text looks like `'begin 666 <data>\n,,3<R+C$V+CDP+CDR\n \nend\n'`.

Comment: when I use type(ipList) i get nothing back.  It doesn't tell me if it's a string or list or whatever it is...   I know I created a list, but there is a type error.  where can that be?

Comment: I was under the impression that the u'string' was the way that minidom rendered that uuencoded text.    am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean you get nothing back? Where are you doing `type(ipList)`? If you've embedded it into a script that you're running and you don't print or log the result you get back, of course you won't see it anywhere. Is that the problem?

Comment: Please read [uuencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) and [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Did you think these were the same thing?

Comment: no...   I I know they are not the same thing... I made an error... it shoud read Unicode... I will fix in the question now.

Comment: Well then, you've got a bunch of Unicode IP addresses. If you get rid of all of the Unicode, you've got nothing left at all. So what exactly _do_ you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go back to your original code. It ends up with this in `ipList`:

```
[u'172.16.60.92', u'172.16.60.89', u'\n              ', u'172.16.60.90', u'172.16.60.91', u'172.16.60.93']
```

The only problem here is that it includes strings full of whitespace, as well as strings with IP addresses in then, right?

So, let's just filter it after the fact:

```
In [51]: ipList = [u'172.16.60.92', u'172.16.60.89', u'\n              ', u'172.16.60.90', u'172.16.60.91', u'172.16.60.93']

In [52]: ipList = [ip for ip in ipList if ip.strip()]

In [53]: ipList
Out[53]: 
['172.16.60.92',
 '172.16.60.89',
 '172.16.60.90',
 '172.16.60.91',
 '172.16.60.93']
```

And you're done!

Why does this work? Well, `ip.strip()` will remove all whitespace from the left and right sides. Sticking the result into an `if` statement, it will be true if there's anything left, and false if there's nothing left.

But obviously you can just move the same condition back into the original loop, putting it before the `append` call, with exactly the same effect:

```
def parseHosts(xmldoc):
  hostsNode = xmldoc.firstChild
  xmlList = hostsNode.getElementsByTagName("ip")

  ipList = []
  for ip in xmlList:
    ipstr = ip.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    if ipstr.strip():
      ipList.append(ipstr)
```

But that whole `ipList` part is obviously just a long-winded version of a list comprehension, so:

```
def parseHosts(xmldoc):
  hostsNode = xmldoc.firstChild
  xmlList = hostsNode.getElementsByTagName("ip")
  ipList = [ip.childNodes[0].nodeValue for ip in xmlList
            if ip.childNodes[0].nodeValue.strip()]
```

As for your attempt to fix this:

```
[m.group(0) for l in ipList for m in [regex.search(1)] if m]
```

Whenever it isn't immediately obvious what a nested list comprehension is doing, break it into two comprehensions.

But let's rewrite that as an explicit loop. Not only does this make it even easier to understand, it makes it a lot easier to debug:

```
result = []
for l in ipList:
    for m in [regex.search(1)]:
        if m:
            result.append(m.group(0))
```

When you run this, you'll get an exception on the third line, and it should be obvious why.

Comment: Excellent!  thank you...   except that I failed to mention that some IPs in the list may not follow my regex.  I want IPs that are only 172.16.*.*...   so I think I need that regex in there somewhere.

Comment: @TheWellington: OK, you should be able to figure out how to add it in. Just change the test from the simple one in your posted problem to the one you actually want using a regex.

Comment: It works up until the part with the regex.  I still get TypeError: expected string or buffer.   Does the regex do something to the type of contents of the list?

Comment: @TheWellington: What list? Look at the parameter you're passing to `regex.search`. (By the way, this is exactly why you usually don't want to name a variable `l`.)

Comment: @TheWellington: Once you fix that: Why would you ever need to do `for m in [anything]:`? That's guaranteed to loop exactly once, setting `m` to `anything`. You could get the exact same effect by doing `m=anything` and removing the loop. Was this supposed to do something else, or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `filter(regex.match,ipList)`:

```
import re
ipList=[u'172.16.60.92', u'172.16.60.89', u'\n              ', u'172.16.60.90', u'172.16.60.91', u'172.16.60.93']
regex = re.compile(r'172\.16\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')
filter(regex.match,ipList)

out:

[u'172.16.60.92',
 u'172.16.60.89',
 u'172.16.60.90',
 u'172.16.60.91',
 u'172.16.60.93']
```